# What is $[\mathbb Z_{12}:\langle5\rangle]_r$?

Tags: group-theory

Somehow I know that $\langle5\rangle$ is a subgroup of integer modulo $12$, well, a generator of course, making it a cyclic subgroup. So, since it is a generator, i figured that $\langle5\rangle$ has an order of $12$. So what i did is i computed $\frac{|G|}{|H|}$, that is, the order of the group (integer $\mod 12$) divided by the order of the subgroup ($\langle5\rangle$). I also know that the order of the group here is $12$, implying that i get $\frac{12}{12}=1$. Therefore my answer is $1$. However, the solution given is 2 instead.

If you could help shed more light upon this problem, would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I don't know what the "r" is, in the title.

Comment: @GerryMyerson it stands for the "right index" of H in G

Comment: All your groups are abelian, so you just want the index of $\langle5\rangle$ in $G={\bf Z}_{12}$. If $G$ is the additive group, you have the right answer.

Comment: I forgot to mention, the reason why i doubted my answer was because the right solution is 2 instead. I need to do some editing to the question.

Comment: Maybe they are taking $G$ to be the multiplicative group instead of the additive one.

Comment: You should realise that (a) the group is abelian and so left cosets are the same as right cosets, so their number is obviously the same, and so the $_r$ is redundant, and (b) in general a subgroup has the same number of left and right cosets, so in general the $_r$ is redundant. It is just especially redundant in abelian groups...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\mathbb Z_{12}$ is the additive group of integers with addition modulo $12$, then your answer is correct, since $\langle 5 \rangle =\mathbb Z_{12}$.

If instead of the additive $\mathbb Z_{12}$ you take the multiplicative $U_{12}=\{1,5,7,11\}$ then $\langle 5 \rangle =\{1,5\}$. In this case $[U_{12}:\langle 5 \rangle]=2$.